# Pandas groupby/pivot dataframe of customer orders

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Right now I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
    name    email           product     qty_ordered
0   jane    jane@email.com  Red Shirt   2
1   john    john@email.com  Green Shirt 2
2   john    john@email.com  Red Shirt   1
3   jim     jim@email.com   Green Shirt 1
4   jim     jim@email.com   Blue Shirt  2
5   bill    bill@email.com  Green Shirt 1
6   jim     jim@email.com   Blue Shirt  1
7   jane    jane@email.com  Blue Shirt  2
8   john    john@email.com  Blue Shirt  1
9   jim     jim@email.com   Green Shirt 2
```

And I am trying to figure out how to get something that looks like this:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
name  email          products    qty_ordered
jane  jane@email.com Red Shirt   2
                     Blue Shirt  2
john  john@email.com Green Shirt 2
                     Blue Shirt  1
                     Red Shirt   1
etc...
```

The data here isn't really whats import just the overall index/column format.

I've tried

`pd.DataFrame(orders).groupby(['name', 'email']).apply(lambda x: x['product'])`

which seems to get close:

```
name  email            
bill  bill@email.com  5    Green Shirt
jane  jane@email.com  0      Red Shirt
                      7     Blue Shirt
jim   jim@email.com   3    Green Shirt
                      4     Blue Shirt
                      6     Blue Shirt
                      9    Green Shirt
john  john@email.com  1    Green Shirt
                      2      Red Shirt
                      8     Blue Shirt
```

But then modifiying that slightly like this:

`pd.DataFrame(orders).groupby(['name', 'email']).apply(lambda x: [['product','qty_ordered']])`

I get this, which I don't understand.

```
    product qty_ordered
0   Red Shirt   2
1   Green Shirt 2
2   Red Shirt   1
3   Green Shirt 1
4   Blue Shirt  2
5   Green Shirt 1
6   Blue Shirt  1
7   Blue Shirt  2
8   Blue Shirt  1
9   Green Shirt 2
```

I have also tried different variations of `df.melt(), df.pivot(), df.agg()` run the gamut of all the usual suspects.

I think I'm missing some fundamental understanding of how `groupby()` actually works. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample input already has  everything what you expected. You just need sort on name? What is summary operation you are trying with groupby?

Comment: My sample input has random names, with their respective product and qty_ordered per each row. I want to group by each unique name and get all products they ordered and the respective qtys.

Comment: According to your sample input, John ordered 1 blue shirt but expected out has 2. Could you justify the scenario? I am unable to understand the problem statement clearly.

Comment: That was a typo. I corrected it. The pivot/grouby format is all that is important to me.

Comment: Then I am confused. Could you highlight your input and expected output?

Comment: The part that says "I have something like this:" is input. The part that says " I am trying to get something like this" is output.

Comment: Could you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['name', 'email', 'product']).agg({'qty_ordered' : 'sum'})
```

Comment: You don't need the `.agg()` here, `df.groupby(["name", "email", "product"]).sum()` should do the same job.

Comment: and how are you going to sum quantity?

Comment: Have you tried it? (`.GroupBy.sum()`s kwarg `numeric_only` is set to `True` by default.)